# Flash swf file to run as an application on android

Tags: android, flash, flash-builder, flash-cs4

I have a flash application(.swf format). I wanted to package the entire swf file and other content(related images, xml files) into a single file and access in a tablet. So basically i need to make it into a single .apk file to access in my tablet. 
         Please let me know if its possible to do it, and what are the tools required to do this.
Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For play swf with android, you need to develop your project in android 2.2 version or above so Flash player 10.3 are install and run which support your swf(shock wave file at background) and you can easily play swf.

You need to drag Webview and attach those swf source path.

you can get player in you mobile from here :: https://market.android.com/details?id=com.adobe.flashplayer&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5hZG9iZS5mbGFzaHBsYXllciJd

Now if you plan to play swf directly, then Adobe Air will help you because it provide sdk in which in Flash you can convert your flash file to apk.(that is the easy to flash developer)

Comment: I want it to be browser independent as well

Answer (score 1):

First, download Flash Professional CS5.5 from [Adobe's site](http://www.adobe.com/products/flash.html) and install it.

Then, read the instructions on [How to publish Android AIR applications](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flash/cs/using/WSb03e830bd6f770ee317e94381294c702634-8000.html)